# Flash CS6 AS3 play sound on one frame only, stop when left frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, flash-cs6

I have a scene which has a frame for each screen that I want to display to the user. Each frame has a movieclip which contains all the elements for that screen. The first frame's movieclip has frame1 set up with a sound layer. Problem is, when I navigate to a different screen, the music continues to play.

How can I get it to only play whilst the movieclip is visible on the screen? I tried to have an "ENTER_FRAME" listener of the other screens and used `SoundMixer.stopAll();` which stopped the music. The only problem is, when I reentered the frame with music, it wouldn't start.

I am using the Sync Setting: Stream.

Answer (score 1):

Flash IDE has a number of different kinds of sounds, the most important being `Stream` and `Event`.

It sounds like you're using an `Event` type sound because the sound continues to play even when you are off the frame. There is no way to stop an `Event` sound except with `SoundMixer.stopAll().`

You need to set the sound type to `Stream` in Flash IDE. Then, place it in a MovieClip and make sure that there enough frames in the clip to last the whole duration of the sound. Then, place that MovieClip in your main scene and it should now stop when you move to a different frame.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that approach, but thought there may have been a simpler way of doing it..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is, but there are quite a few ways that are even more complicated, if you'd like.

Comment: The sound still doesn't stop when I move to the next frame when I used Stream. Any idea why it wouldn't?

Comment: Sometimes Flash can glitch if there is a `Stream` type sound in a MovieClip that is just one frame.